# How to separate a microbial strain of MTB resistant and susceptible drugwise?

Tags: python, perl, text-processing

Im trying to classify my list into three type: XDR - A strain must be resistant to:

```
MDR + CIPROFLOXACIN/MOXIFLOXACIN/OFLOXACIN/LEVOFLOXACIN + AMYCACIN/CAPREOMYCIN/KANAMYCIN-> means ISONIAZID + RIFAMPICIN + any of these or two or three or all (CIPROFLOXACIN/MOXIFLOXACIN/OFLOXACIN/LEVOFLOXACIN) + any of these or two or three or all (AMYCACIN/CAPREOMYCIN/KANAMYCIN)
```

PRE-XDR - A strain must be resistant to:

```
MDR + CIPROFLOXACIN/MOXIFLOXACIN/OFLOXACIN/LEVOFLOXACIN -> means ISONIAZID + RIFAMPICIN + any of these or two or three or all (CIPROFLOXACIN/MOXIFLOXACIN/OFLOXACIN/LEVOFLOXACIN)
```

MDR - A strain must be resistant to:

```
ISONIAZID + RIFAMPICIN 
and if it is resistant to any one/two/three of these or all of these in 
addition to ISONIAZID + RIFAMPICIN than again it is MDR:- 
PYRAZINAMIDE, ETHIONAMIDE, STREPTOMYCIN, ETHAMBUTOL
```

SUSCEPTIBLE - A strain must be Susceptible to all drugs

I tried the code as follows for MDR:

```
tail -n +2 drug.txt |\
awk '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2};END{for(i in a)print i"\t"a[i]}'|\
grep -P "\t,ISONIAZID,RIFAMPICIN$"
```

It gave me MDR starins correctly but than i had to first remove all Susceptible strains and applied it to Resistant one only.

But when i applied the code for Pre-XDR:

```
tail -n +2 drug.txt |\
awk '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2};END{for(i in a)print i"\t"a[i]}'|\
grep -P 
"\t,ISONIAZID,RIFAMPICIN|CIPROFLOXACIN|MOXIFLOXACIN|OFLOXACIN|LEVOFLOXACIN"
```

It is giving me the result as below:

```
SRR671821       ,CAPREOMYCIN,ETHAMBUTOL,ETHIONAMIDE,ISONIAZID,KANAMYCIN,OFLOXACIN,RIFAMPICIN,STREPTOMYCIN
SRR671863       ,CAPREOMYCIN,ETHAMBUTOL,ISONIAZID,KANAMYCIN,OFLOXACIN,RIFAMPICIN
SRR671822       ,ETHAMBUTOL,ISONIAZID,OFLOXACIN,RIFAMPICIN,STREPTOMYCIN
SRR671864       ,CAPREOMYCIN,ETHAMBUTOL,ISONIAZID,KANAMYCIN,OFLOXACIN,RIFAMPICIN
```

Which is not correct for Pre-XDR.

So I'm looking for a the drugs if match than look for resistant and susceptible if these criteria match with any of the mention type (MDR,XDR...) it put those under that in a new file. Can anyone help? 
my file [druglist.sxls](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TOYNzcwzoBdgpUCA3d45mg2VTCRa4zyB)

MDR eg from the file attached is:

```
ERR038736   ISONIAZID   RESISTANT
ERR038736   RIFAMPICIN  RESISTANT
ERR038737   ISONIAZID   RESISTANT
ERR038737   RIFAMPICIN  RESISTANT
SRR1270146  AMIKACIN    SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  CAPREOMYCIN SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  CYCLOSERINE SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  ETHAMBUTOL  RESISTANT   
SRR1270146  ETHIONAMIDE SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  ISONIAZID   RESISTANT   
SRR1270146  KANAMYCIN   SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  PARA-AMINOSALICYLIC ACID    SUSCEPTIBLE 
SRR1270146  PYRAZINAMIDE    RESISTANT   
SRR1270146  RIFAMPICIN  RESISTANT   
SRR1270146  STREPTOMYCIN    RESISTANT
```

Comment: Why did you delete your original question hat already had an answer?

Comment: Hi @terdon I didn't deleted that question and the answers were removed by itself and it went to solved category it self thats why i have to repost the question.

Comment: Well the answer was deleted by the user who posted it, yes, but the question was deleted by you.  Note that there is no such thing as "solved category", I am not sure what you mean by that. Anyway, don't worry about it, just try not to delete and repost questions in general since it confuses things. But no big deal.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was incorrect (your question was correct and could receive answers from other people). I could try to answer it again with base R, but I will need more time

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of `drug.txt`

Comment: I have editted my question and have put a small data from my drug.csv file. I have also uploaded the whole file as well.

Comment: @llrs Thankyou. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Also asked 6 weeks ago on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/344050/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this involves combining multiple conditions, it is easier (and certainly more readable if you ever need to come back to it later) to write a script to do this. For example, in perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

## This will hold the information for each strain
my %strains;

## These are the functions that will test each strain
sub isMDR{
  my $_strain = shift;
  my %thisStrain = %{$strains{$_strain}};
  if ($thisStrain{"ISONIAZID"} && $thisStrain{"RIFAMPICIN"}){
    foreach my $drug (keys(%thisStrain)) {
      next if $drug eq "ISONIAZID";
      next if $drug eq "RIFAMPICIN";
      next if $drug eq "PYRAZINAMID";
      next if $drug eq "ETHAMBUTOL";
      next if $drug eq "STREPTOMYCIN";
      ## discard this strain if it is resistant to any other drug
      if ($thisStrain{$drug}) {
        return 0;
      }
    }

    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

sub isPreXDR{
  my $_strain = shift;
  my %thisStrain = %{$strains{$_strain}};
  if (
  ($thisStrain{"ISONIAZID"} && $thisStrain{"RIFAMPICIN"}) &&
  (
   $thisStrain{"CIPROFLOXACIN"}  ||
       $thisStrain{"MOXIFLOXACIN"} ||
   $thisStrain{"OFLOXACIN"}  ||
       $thisStrain{"LEVOFLOXACIN"}
      )
     ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

sub isXDR{
  my $_strain = shift;
  my %thisStrain = %{$strains{$_strain}};
  if (
  isPreXDR($_strain) &&
      (
       $thisStrain{"AMYCACIN"} ||
   $thisStrain{"CAPREOMYCIN"} ||
       $thisStrain{"KANAMYCIN"}
      )
     ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

sub isSusceptible{
  my $_strain = shift;
  foreach my $drug (keys(%{$strains{$_strain}})) {
if ($strains{$_strain}{$drug}) {
      return 0
    }
  }
  return 1
}

## Iterate over each line in the input file.
## For each iteration, the special variable $_
# will hold the contents of the line.
while (<>) {
  ## Skip first line
  next if $. == 1;
  ## remove Windows-style line endings
  s/\r//;
  ## remove trailing newline
  chomp;
  ## split the line on commas
  my ($strain, $drug, $status) = split(/,/);
  if ($status eq "SUSCEPTIBLE"){
$status = 0
  }
  else {
$status = 1;
  } 
  $strains{$strain}{$drug}=$status;
}

foreach my $strain (keys(%strains)) {
  print "$strain\t";
  if (isMDR($strain)) {
print "MDR\n";
  }
  elsif (isXDR($strain)) {
print "XDR\n"
  }
  elsif (isPreXDR($strain)) {
print "PRE-XDR\n"
  }
  elsif (isSusceptible($strain)) {
    print "SUSCEPTIBLE\n";
  }
  else {
    print "OTHER\n";
  }
}
```

If you save that script as `foo.pl`, you can run it on your file with:

```
perl foo.pl drug.csv
```

Selected output from running this on the `drug.csv` file you posted is:

```
$ foo.pl drug.csv | grep -E 'ERR038288|ERR038736|ERR038751|SRS553990|ERR133879'
ERR038751   OTHER
ERR038288   SUSCEPTIBLE
SRS553990   XDR
ERR038736   MDR
ERR133879   PRE-XDR
```

---

Various details about this question were added in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47821646#47821646

Comment: It is again not correct like for MDR -ERR047000 - It is a Susceptible strain.

ERR047000 ETHAMBUTOL SUSCEPTIBLE
ERR047000 ISONIAZID SUSCEPTIBLE
ERR047000 PYRAZINAMIDE SUSCEPTIBLE
ERR047000 RIFAMPICIN SUSCEPTIBLE


Same for MDR -> ERS389515:

ERS389515 ETHAMBUTOL SUSCEPTIBLE
ERS389515 ISONIAZID SUSCEPTIBLE
ERS389515 PYRAZINAMIDE SUSCEPTIBLE
ERS389515 RIFAMPICIN SUSCEPTIBLE
ERS389515 STREPTOMYCIN SUSCEPTIBLE
It is susceptible not MDR

Comment: @SafinaA.R what is wrong? It is very hard to test since you haven't given examples of what we should see. The example in your question isn't listed in the drugs.csv file. Can you ping me (`@terdon`) in our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics) so we can discuss this?

Comment: HI. I think it is now running fine. So now i have the proper classification verified by my team. So any thing that is resistant to ISONIASID and RIfampicin is mdr but it can also be mdr if these two are there plus any of these or all of these: Pyrazinamid, Ethambutal, Streptomycin, ETHIONAMIDE. like these are the few example of mdr from the list:

`ERR038736
ERR038737
ERR038738
ERR038739
ERR038740
ERR038742
ERR038743
ERR038744
ERR038745
ERR038746
ERR038747
ERR038748
ERR038749
ERR038750
ERR038752
ERR046855`

Comment: Few Examples:

`ERR038288 Susc
ERR038736 MDR
ERR038751 Others
SRS553990 XDR
ERR133879 Pre-XDR`

Comment: @SafinaA.R all of those are caught correctly by the latest version.

Comment: Great. Correctly classified. THUMBS UP.